# Trouble showing desired MAX outcome when using a view and a WHERE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Attempting to show the maximum number of items in my NumberofUnits column, where the ProductDescription starts with the letter P. My goal is to only show one result, it should be showing only one instance of "Pants" where the NumberOfUnits is the largest. Instead it is producing more than one instance, and not showing the maximum of any. I have tried it two different ways and neither has produced what I am looking for.

I should mention my goal is to run this stored procedure against my table view. How would I fix this issue to get the result I am looking for, is it even possible to use an aggregate like MAX in a stored procedure when it is running against a table view? If so, what do I need to do to change it to make it work? (This is for a homework issue in my class)

First I created a table view and a stored procedure to attempt to solve this in two different ways. One using the MAX function in the stored procedure only, the second using it in the table view only. Neither produced the results I expected.

--TableView attempt

```
create view [dbo].[inventoryinfo1_vw] as
select InventoryOrdering.NumberOfUnits, InventoryOrdering.DateOfOrder, Product.ProductDescription, Product.ListPrice, Supplier.Name, Supplier.PhoneNumber
from Supplier
join InventoryOrdering
on InventoryOrdering.SupplierID = Supplier.SupplierID
join Product
on Product.ProductNO = InventoryOrdering.ProductNO
group by DateofOrder, ProductDescription, ListPrice, Name, PhoneNumber
```

--Stored procedure attempt

```
create procedure MaxInfo
as 
begin
    select MAX(NumberOfUnits) AS 'Largest Quantity', ProductDescription
    from [dbo].[inventoryinfo1_vw]
    where ProductDescription LIKE 'P%'
    group by ProductDescription
    order by ProductDescription
end
```

I wanted to see only the one row with the highest numberofunits, that started with P, instead it is producing two rows, how do I prevent this from occurring?

The code above resulted in the following:

```
Largest Quantity        ProductDescription
     8                     Pants
    12                     Pants
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view modify it like this:

```
create view [dbo].[inventoryinfo1_vw] as
   select InventoryOrdering.NumberOfUnits, InventoryOrdering.DateOfOrder, TRIM(Product.ProductDescription) AS ProductDescription, Product.ListPrice, Supplier.Name, Supplier.PhoneNumber
-- etc
```